# Unit test MVVM commands

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, mvvm, icommand

I have a new WPF MVVM project and would like to write "some useful" unit tests for my ViewModel.

My ViewModel class:

```
public class ConsignorViewModel : ViewModel
{
    ...
    #region Commands
    void NewModel()
    {
        _model = new Consignor();

        RaisePropertyChanged(String.Empty, validatePropertyName: false);
    }
    void SaveModel()
    {
        ... //some logic to save
    }

    public override ICommand New { get { return new RelayCommand(NewModel); } }
    public override ICommand Save { get { return new RelayCommand(SaveModel); } }
    #endregion
}
```

I would like to unit test those commands. What is the best way to do so?

At the moment my unit test method just looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCommands()
{
    //Arrange

    //Act

    //Assert
    ////New Command
    Assert.IsNotNull(_consignorViewModel.New);
    Assert.IsTrue(_consignorViewModel.New is RelayCommand);

    ////Save Command
    Assert.IsNotNull(_consignorViewModel.Save);
    Assert.IsTrue(_consignorViewModel.Save is RelayCommand);
}
```

I would like to test the behaviour/result of an command.
When testing the "new" command I would like to ensure that the model is "reset" (constructor call). At the moment this is not possible as my methods "NewModel" and "SaveModel" are not visible in the unit test which is correct as they're not part of the public interface. So I don't want to make them public ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At the moment this is not possible as my methods "NewModel" and "SaveModel" are not visible in the unit test which is correct as they're not part of the public interface.

And they shouldn't be. You already know the solution to this problem, you even said it yourself:

> I would like to test the behaviour/result of an command.

That's the point. With unit tests we verify *observable effects*. How does the user recognise that model has been reset? User has no knowledge of `New` method, nor should unit test. If `New` method has no obeservable side effect, visible from public POV, then you might just as well remove it from your code base.

Identify those publicly visible changes and test against them.

Comment: The user has knowledge. If the user has done some input and afterwards the "New" command is called, the complete model is reset, so the input is gone.

Comment: @mosquito87: there goes your test. I assume your VM exposes some public fields which are then bound to UI. In test you could set values to said fields, call `New` and verify that those set values are gone. This is the observable behavior here. My point being, user does not know there's something called `New` that calls some constructor. User knows what he can see/observe/experience.

Comment: You're right. I'm calling the execute() and testing, if the properties are "reset". Thanks!